# Mapping to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I was trying to map a csv file so that each record would simply be a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

I am receiving an

> ArgumentException "Not a member access;"

When I try to do this. Code included below:

```
public class CsvFileReader : FileReader
{
    public CsvFileReader(string path) : base(path){ }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Read()
    {
        var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(Path));
        reader.Read();
        reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new DictionaryClassMap(reader.FieldHeaders));
        return reader.GetRecord<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    }

    private class DictionaryClassMap : CsvClassMap<Dictionary<string, object>>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<string> _headers;

        public DictionaryClassMap(IEnumerable<string> headers)
        {
            _headers = headers;
        }

        public override void CreateMap()
        {
            foreach (var header in _headers)
            {
                var localHeader = header;
                Map(x => x[localHeader]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there currently is no support for mapping to a `Dictionary`.

If you try doing `GetRecords<Dictionary<string, object>>()`, you will get an error.

```
Types that inhererit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?
```

You can't map to a `Dictionary` either. In a mapping you need to specify a property of the class for the field to be mapped to. The indexer is not a member property which is why you're getting that error.

**SOLUTION:**

What you CAN do is this:

```
var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>();
```

You can use it as a dynamic object.

**DESIRED SOLUTION**

Internally, it uses the `ExpandoObject`, so you can do this.

```
var dict = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>() as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

Comment: Just wondering if this is still the case? Is it safe to cast the `dynamic` to an `IDictionary<string,object>` or is there a different way of getting a dictionary from a CSV file.?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do similar (although not reading all the columns into the `Dictionary`, just some). So, in case this is of use, (and strongly aided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363744/)) you can have a `Dictionary` as a property of a class and then populate that (as Josh say's you can't populate a `Dictionary` on it's own as CsvHelper is expecting a member property to map to).

The below would map to a property `DictionaryProperty` which is a `Dictionary<string,string>` of the class `MyClassWithDictionaryMapper`.

```
public class MyClassWithDictionaryMapper: ClassMap<MyClassWithDictionary>
{
    public MyClassWithDictionaryMapper(List<string> headers)
    {

        Map(m => m.DictionaryProperty).ConvertUsing
           (row => headers.Select
            (column => new { column, value = row.GetField(column) })
            .ToDictionary(d => d.column, d => d.value)
            );
    }
}
```