# CsvHelper write mapper one property to multiple columns

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using csvHelper (version 2.8.4) to write a class to csv.
My class looks like this:

```
public class classA
{
   public int Amount { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, string> Dict{ get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to write a mapper that maps `Dict` property to multiple columns? using some sort of converter?

for example if the class has the values:

Amount = 15

Dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{["a1"] = "a2",["b1"] = "b2"}

I want the resulting csv to be:

```
Amount,a1,b1
15,a2,b2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311423/mapping-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Thanks, ill check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way is going to be to manually write out the dictionary part.

*** Update to work with CsvHelper Version 2.8.4 ***

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<classA>
    {
        new classA {
            Amount = 15,
            Dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{["a1"] = "a2",["b1"] = "b2"}
        }
    };
    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
    {
        var dict = records.First().Dict;

        var properties = typeof(classA).GetProperties();
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name != "Dict")
            {
                csv.WriteField(property.Name);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            csv.WriteField(item.Key);
        }

        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Name != "Dict")
                {
                    csv.WriteField(property.GetValue(record));
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in record.Dict)
            {
                csv.WriteField(item.Value);
            }

            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public class classA
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

*** Works for current Version 27.2.1 ***

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<classA>
    {
        new classA { Amount = 15, Dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{["a1"] = "a2",["b1"] = "b2"} },
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var dict = records.First().Dict;
        
        csv.WriteHeader<classA>();
        
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            csv.WriteField(item.Key);   
        }
        
        csv.NextRecord();
        
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(record);

            foreach (var item in record.Dict)
            {
                csv.WriteField(item.Value);
            }
            
            csv.NextRecord();
        }       
    }
}

public class classA
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which version of csvHelper did you use? doing as you suggested causes whatever I write in csv.WriteField be in a new line

Comment: The newest version.  Which version are you using?  I don't remember a time when `csv.WriteField` would write a newline.

Comment: A really old version . 2.8.4, it's in a legacy system

Comment: Using 2.8.4, it looks like `csv.WriteHeader<classA>()` and `csv.WriteRecord(record)` both cause the writing of a `newline` character.  Not writing a `newline` character for both of those methods must have been an upgrade at some point.  I'll update my answer to work for Version 2.8.4.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in linked question, you may use `ExpandoObject` to serialize dictionary.

The following code will work for writing to CSV only, it's converting `classA` objects to `ExpandoObject` during serialization, including `Amount` property which is added manually.

```
public static List<dynamic> ToExpandoObjects(IReadOnlyList<classA> aObjects)
{
    var allKeys = aObjects
        .SelectMany(a => a.Dict.Keys)
        .Distinct()
        .ToHashSet();

    var result = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var a in aObjects)
    {
        var asExpando = new ExpandoObject();
        var asDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)asExpando;

        asDictionary[nameof(classA.Amount)] = a.Amount;
        foreach (var key in allKeys)
        {
            if(a.Dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
                asDictionary[key] = value;
            else
                asDictionary[key] = null;
        }

        result.Add(asExpando);
    }

    return result;
}

...
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(ToExpandoObjects(records));
    }
```

E.g. called as:

```
var records = new[] {
    new classA
    {
        Amount = 15,
        Dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{["a1"] = "a2",["b1"] = "b2"}
    },
    new classA
    {
        Amount = 15,
        Dict = new Dictionary<string,string>{["c1"] = "c2",["b1"] = "b2"}
    }
};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(ToExpandoObjects(records));
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

produces

| Amount | a1 | b1 | c1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | a2 | b2 |  |
| 15 |  | b2 | c2 |